# Linux C, Why fcntl act on STDIN will also affect on STDOUT and STDERR?

Tags: c, linux

I have met a problem when acting function `fcntl` on `stdin`, when I set the `stdin` FD status flag to `O_NONBLOCK`, It works well but within a side effect. The status flag of stdout and stderr has also changed to `O_NONBLOCK`.

I investigated the source code of function `fcntl`, `SYSCALL_DEFINE3` and `do_fcntl`, but got nothing helps. Also stackoverflow or google. I consider that it may related to kernel or glibc implementation.

My computer is Ubuntu 12.04 on x86_64, within gcc 4.6.3 installed.

```
  int flag = 0;
  int value = O_NONBLOCK;
  int fd = open("./tmp", O_RDONLY);

  if(-1 == (flag = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL)))
      fprintf(stdout, "%d:%s\n", errno, strerror(errno));

  flag = fcntl(stdin->_fileno, F_GETFL);
  flag = fcntl(stderr->_fileno, F_GETFL);
  if(-1 == (flag = fcntl(stdout->_fileno, F_GETFL)))
      fprintf(stdout, "%d:%s\n", errno, strerror(errno));

  flag = fcntl(stdout->_fileno, F_SETFL, flag | O_NONBLOCK);

  flag = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
  flag = fcntl(stdin->_fileno, F_GETFL);
  flag = fcntl(stdout->_fileno, F_GETFL);
  flag = fcntl(stderr->_fileno, F_GETFL);

  flag = fcntl(stdin->_fileno, F_SETFL, flag | O_APPEND);

  flag = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
  flag = fcntl(stdin->_fileno, F_GETFL);
  flag = fcntl(stdout->_fileno, F_GETFL);
  flag = fcntl(stderr->_fileno, F_GETFL);

  close(fd);
```

This is my code for this problem.

Comment: How about posting some code?

Comment: Have you tried when you don't use a tty (e.g. `echo "" | ./your_program`)?

Comment: Yes. Thanks! I just `gdb a.out`, and display flag, when set O_NONBLOCK to stdout, and I got stdin and stderr all has O_NONBLOCK. It is confused.~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the 'tricks' traditionally used by the login process (or terminal opening process) is to open the terminal in read-write mode for file descriptor 0 (standard input), and then duplicate that for file descriptors 1 and 2 (standard output and standard error).  This means that:

1. All three standard file descriptors share the same open file description.
2. You can write to standard input and read from standard output or standard error.
3. Changing the file description information for one changes it for the others.

The F_GETFL and F_SETFL options to `fcntl()` are related to the open file description.
The F_GETFD and F_SETFD options to `fcntl()` are related to the file descriptor.

A given open file description may have several file descriptors associated with, either within a single process (after `dup()` or `dup2()`) or across processes (because of `fork()`).

Comment: Yes. Thanks, CSAPP say there are three types of opened file, file descriptor, xxx(I forget its name, who holds quote count and offset) and vnode. There is only one open file descriptor exactly. Thanks very much, help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Following from Jonathan's answer, here's some saner code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void show_nonblock_status(void) {
    char streams[3][7] = {"stdin", "stdout", "stderr"};

    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i ) {
        int flag = fcntl(i, F_GETFL);
        if ( flag == -1 ) {
            perror("error getting flags");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if ( flag & O_NONBLOCK ) {
            printf("O_NONBLOCK is set for %s\n", streams[i]);
        } else {
            printf("O_NONBLOCK is not set for %s\n", streams[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    show_nonblock_status();

    int flag = fcntl(1, F_GETFL);
    if ( flag == -1 ) {
        perror("error getting flags");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    flag = fcntl(1, F_SETFL, flag | O_NONBLOCK);
    if ( flag == -1 ) {
        perror("error getting flags");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    show_nonblock_status();

    return 0;
}
```

which gives the following output under various uses:

```
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ ./fct
O_NONBLOCK is not set for stdin
O_NONBLOCK is not set for stdout
O_NONBLOCK is not set for stderr
O_NONBLOCK is set for stdin
O_NONBLOCK is set for stdout
O_NONBLOCK is set for stderr
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ cat testfile | ./fct
O_NONBLOCK is not set for stdin
O_NONBLOCK is not set for stdout
O_NONBLOCK is not set for stderr
O_NONBLOCK is not set for stdin
O_NONBLOCK is set for stdout
O_NONBLOCK is set for stderr
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ cat testfile | ./fct 2>/dev/null
O_NONBLOCK is not set for stdin
O_NONBLOCK is not set for stdout
O_NONBLOCK is not set for stderr
O_NONBLOCK is not set for stdin
O_NONBLOCK is set for stdout
O_NONBLOCK is not set for stderr
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$
```

In the first case, the file description is the same, so `O_NONBLOCK` is set for all three.

In the second case, a file is piped to `stdin`, so that has a different file description to `stdout` and `stderr`, both of which have `O_NONBLOCK` set.

In the third case, a file is piped to `stdin`, and `stderr` is redirected to `/dev/null`, so all 3 file descriptions are different, and `O_NONBLOCK` is only set for `stdout`.